# I cant move my contrent .... in my main?

Tags: html, css, element

EDIT#2: Fixed it i have added to my code `position: absolute; top 130px; display:block;` thanks for all respondes ... code on codepen was fixed too .. :D

EDIT: So i fixed the content-holder problem now i have a new one i cant move him inside my main .... i have been trying vertical align and it doesnt work   Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvKdrL

My new code :

```css
header>a
{
 font-size: 38px;
 font-weight: 500;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
 text-align: left;
 color: #555;
 font-family: "Monserat";
}

header
{
 border-bottom:1px solid #888;
}

main
{
 height: 530px;
 display: block;
 margin-top: -40px;
}

ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
}

li a
{

 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 margin: 4px;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 line-height: 34px;
 color: #222;
}

a
{
 text-decoration: none;
}

li::before
{
 content: "➢";
}

.center
{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-holder
{
 position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 130px;
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;    
}

.background
{
 z-index: 1;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.footer
{
 border-top: 1px solid #888;
 height: 20px;
 content:
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header class="center">
  <a href="index.html" class="header">Name</a>
 </header>
 <main class="center sizemain">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content-holder">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="special" target="_blank">List </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">List </a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">List</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">List</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">List</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </main>

  <footer class="footer">

  </footer>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for respondes

Comment: Your `.content-holder` class has a `50px` top margin. Also browsers will apply default CSS, which you'll need to override - such as margin and padding on elements (the `ul` tag for example). You might want to check out a reset css file - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: im using normalize css and i deleted my margin-top as you said and now my content holder is on the border and now how to positon my .content-holder

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment out both the margin-top **and** the margin. Margin applies 50px to every side.

```
.content-holder {
    width: 250px;
    height: 190px;
    background: #eee;
    /* margin: 30px; */
    /* margin-top: 50px; */
    vertical-align: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: i did but i need to center my content holder to right place vertical align doesnt work ...